# How to perform an action when Selecting one of results of UISearchController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a table of names and I have a search bar on the top of it.  I need to perform an action when one of the result rows selected, which is hide the table view and show another view.

In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I am doing the following:

```
if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {                
     Selection =  [searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     tableView.hidden = YES;
     DetailView.hidden = NO;               
}
```

Also I have tried

```
if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
```

I don't have another controller to use "Segue", both of my views are in the same controller.

Comment: Are you sure your delegate is setup?  Does your if statement get called?

Comment: @ansible, well in the if statement I am printing the "Selection" string, which is the selected row from the result, which means it does response to the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted the problem by bringing the wanted view to the front

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:BuildingView];
```